# Delete entire index in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm approaching ElastichSearch with a Java client. I'm trying to delete an entire index. I'm able to delete a single document with the following code:

```
DeleteResponse response = client.prepareDelete("twitter", "tweet", "1").get();
```

I would like to delete all documents for a given index in a single instruction. Note that I'm using the version 2.2.

Thanks

EDIT: I've found a similar question but it refers to an old API version. I'm currently working with version 2.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to erase ElasticSearch index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019221/how-to-erase-elasticsearch-index)

Comment: The problem is essentially the same, but the API in 2.2 version (the current, that I need) are slightly different

Comment: try using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to delete your index, then recreate it.

```
DeleteIndexResponse deleteResponse = client.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest("your-index")).actionGet()
```

then

```
client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("your-index").get();
```

This will work with the 2.2 api

Comment: Do you have any idea on how same could be achieved with Java High Level Rest Client. This works fine with transport client but now it is deprecated by elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as in maximede's answer but using newer version of `RestHighLevelClient` (non depreciated):

```java
// delete current index
var deleteRequest = new DeleteIndexRequest("index-name");
client.indices().delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

// create new one
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("index-name");
client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Please make sure to import from the right package:

```java
org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest
org.elasticsearch.client.indices.CreateIndexRequest;
```

Works fine with micronaut framework `io.micronaut.elasticsearch:micronaut-elasticsearch:4.0.0`